# how to improve this algorithm for combinations?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, statistics, combinations

I have this problem, I need to find a combination with specific numbers, and the sum of the numbers should be a other specific amount, i think that you can understand me with the code.

```
function get4() {

    function iter(temp) {
        return function (v) {
            var t = temp.concat(v);
            if (t.length === 4) {
                if (t.reduce(add) === 10) {
                    result.push(t);
                }
                return;
            }
            values.forEach(iter(t));
        };
    }

    const
        add = (a, b) => a + b,
        values = [1, 2, 3, 4],
        result = [];

    values.forEach(iter([]));
    return result;
}

console.log(get4().map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

with this code I can find a 4 digits that his sum is 10, with little numbers works, but if a try with bigger numbers, the function crash, I mean, the browser not execute it.

my problema is with this data

length = `493`

the sum is = `42990`

and the values are = `[500,400,300,200,100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10,5]`

how can I improve this code? if you have another solution in other language, it would also help me.

Comment: improve in what way? speed? aesthetics?

Comment: oh, you mean *improve* as in *make it work* - sorry, didn't read the whole question where you mentioned the crashing part

Comment: well I need that the browser can execute it, if it were faster, I'd be happy,

Comment: do you get an error with your current code?

Comment: Since you tagged this JavaScript I will not post this as a formal answer, but I would solve it as a [Constraint satisfaction problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem), e.g. [Constraint Logic Programming](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clp)

Comment: @JaromandaX nop, when i tried to excute the code on chrome console, the console is freeze, and i can't execute other command

Comment: Do you need to remove duplicates from the `result`? Like [1,1,4,4] & [1,4,1,4] & ... [4,4,1,1], leaving only one, for example [1,1,4,4]

Answer (score 0):

You could:

```js
// comments removed for simplicity
function combinationSumRecursive(
  candidates,
  remainingSum,
  finalCombinations = [],
  currentCombination = [],
  startFrom = 0,
) {
  if (remainingSum < 0) {
    return finalCombinations;
  }

  if (remainingSum === 0) {
    finalCombinations.push(currentCombination.slice());

    return finalCombinations;
  }
  
  for (let candidateIndex = startFrom; candidateIndex < candidates.length; candidateIndex += 1) {
    const currentCandidate = candidates[candidateIndex];

    currentCombination.push(currentCandidate);

    combinationSumRecursive(
      candidates,
      remainingSum - currentCandidate,
      finalCombinations,
      currentCombination,
      candidateIndex,
    );

    currentCombination.pop();
  }

  return finalCombinations;
}

function removesDuplicatesAndNon4Length(arr) {
  return arr.map(x => [...new Set(x)]).filter(x => x.length === 4); 
}

const tempResp = combinationSumRecursive([1, 2, 3, 4], 10);
const resp = removesDuplicatesAndNon4Length(tempResp);

console.log(resp);
```

Note: This is a [Combination Sum Problem](https://github.com/trekhleb/javascript-algorithms/tree/master/src/algorithms/sets/combination-sum) version modificated for this specific program.

Comment: This code doesn't look more optimized. Especially the part with `removesDuplicatesAndNon4Length()`. Why generate sums of more that 4 numbers?

Comment: And it's not clear if `resp` / `result` should contain only one variant (probably not - original `result` contains several variants), and if there should be no duplicates like [1,2,3,4] & [4,3,2,1] & etc.